# How to view and change the assignment of keyboard shortcuts to existing macros?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

In Microsoft Excel 2010, I have a macro assigned to a keyboard shortcut.  Strangely, it's not working properly.  I want to double-check the keyboard binding.

How can I view and/or change the assignment of keyboard shortcuts to existing macros?

When you initially create a macro, you can assign it to a `Ctrl+<key>` keyboard shortcut, as in this screenshot:

[image]

But I can't find anywhere in the UI to view and/or change the existing bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to view and change the mapping of keyboard shortcuts to macros in Excel is *completely different* than in Word.  Maybe that's what's tripping you up.

In Excel:

- In the Ribbon, click View → Macros dropdown → View Macros.  That will display the "Macro" dialog.
- In the "Macro" dialog, click on a macro and then click the "Option" button.  That will display the "Macro Options" dialog.

The "Macro Options" dialog is where you can change the assigned keyboard shortcut.

You can see an example of that dialog here:

[image]

Comment: I found the answer immediately after asking my question, so I answered it.  Since it does in fact work differently in Excel than in Word, I would bet a significant sum of money that other people have been and will be tripped up in the same way as I was, so I thought I'd introduce some levity.  <robotVoice>Ha ha ha</robotVoice>.